# Get the arrays which are inside array with a certain condition in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, arrays

I have got an array like this:

```
var array1=[['1','name1','surname1'],['2','name2','surname2'],['2','name3','surname3'],['3','name4','surname4']];
```

I would like to get a new array with the elements with id 2:

```
var array2=[['2','name2','surname2'],['2','name3','surname3']];
```

The id is always in the same position.

I have got this format because It is an arraylist that I have got from C#.

I can do it with Javascript or Jquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a very handy filter method that can be used for all sorts of things, but is perfect for this as it returns an array.

Try this...

```
var array2 = $(array1).filter(function() { return this[0] == "2"; });
```

In the filter function `this` is each element of the original array.  We simply check the 1st element of that and compare it to the required value.  If the function returns `true`, `this` is added to the results.

Comment: I was half way into writing a `$(array1).each(...)` answer but yours made me feel ashamed... +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, filter method exists in plain javascript as well.

```
array1.filter(function(e){ 
return e[0] == '2'; 
})
```